# Docker. Django manage.py runserver

Tags: django, docker

работаю в debian 9.6.1 из под root
создаю проект

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/data --rm -it mydjango django-admin.py startproject mynewproject
```

все ОК! 
но при старте

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/data --rm -it mydjango ./mynewproject manage.py runserver
```

вылезают ошибка пермишен

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"./mynewproject\": permission denied": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Как быть, я же из под рута работаю!?
файл Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
RUN pip install django
RUN mkdir /data
RUN chmod +x -R /data
WORKDIR /data
```

Comment: А при чём тут рут, если файлу скорее всего просто никто не пометил файл исполняемым

Comment: В файле  Dockerfile указал нотацию chmod +x, все также вылетает с ошибкой.

Comment: `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: @floydya  К сожалению не помогло

Comment: @Vadim так а что пишет? Та же ошибка?

Comment: @floydya Да, все та же ошибка

Comment: `docker run -v `pwd`:/data --rm -it mydjango python mynewproject/manage.py runserver` а так? Что Вы вообще пытаетесь сделать `./mynewproject` этим? Перейти в директорию и выполнить manage.py оттуда?

Comment: @floydya Спасибо, ./mynewproject/manage.py runserver у меня был тупо пропущен слеш.